# Twitter web intent to post image?

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to attach an image to a tweet via [Twitter's Web Intents](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents)?  Right now, if you put an image in the message, the full URL of the image is put into the message, instead of the shortened and attached image URL...

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.website.com%2F&text=MyText+http%3A%2F%2Fwww.website.com%2Fimg%2Fimage.png&url=www.someurl.com
```

[Click here](https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.website.com%2F&text=MyText+http%3A%2F%2Fwww.website.com%2Fimg%2Fimage.png&url=www.someurl.com) to see the result (no attached image, just a full image url in the message....)

When you paste in an image URL into a tweet on Twitter.com, the image URL is automatically shortened and the image is attached to the tweet, so it shows the image when you view the tweet. I'm looking for something similar with the Web Intents.

Answer (score 15):

You can *not* attach an image, but you *can* use a [Twitter Card](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/overview).

> With Twitter Cards, you can attach rich photos, videos and media experience to Tweets that drive traffic to your website.

Essentially, you need to add some metadata to your page. When Twitter sees that, it will automatically insert an image into the Tweet.

For a [single photo](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/photo), you would need to put this code on each page (put in your own details)

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="photo" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@example" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="My picture" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="A description" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://example.com/test.jpg" />
<meta name="twitter:url" content="http://example.com/mypage.html" />
```

Comment: Photo cards are deprecated as of now.

Comment: True - you should probably use a summary card with large image https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary-large-image

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think this answers the OP's question - Twitter Cards are for viewing existing tweets; the question was regarding creating a new tweet.

Answer (score 12):

First, you will need to post the image in a tweet to twitter.

Next, go to the tweet URL.  It will be something like `https://twitter.com/yourtwitterhandle/status/783356010631016448`.  View the source for that page and search for `pic.twitter.com`.  You'll find a link to a URL that looks like `pic.twitter.com/JvCvCquBlf`.

Simply add that link to the content of your web intent URL and it will display when the user posts.  It won't share in the tweet preview screen, but once they click 'tweet', it will be added

[image]

Example URL: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dataquest.io%2Fblog%2Fpython-pandas-databases%2F&via=dataquestio&text=Working%20with%20SQLite%20Databases%20using%20Python%20and%20Pandas%20pic.twitter.com/JvCvcquBlf&hashtags=sql%2CDataScience&

Comment: Great! Thanks Josh

Comment: @MaciejKrawczyk there's only one way to find out ;)

Comment: "First, you will need to post the image in a tweet to twitter." How do you exactly automate this, if I may ask?

Comment: I just do it manually, since I only use this once a week.  You can automate this though, using the twitter API: https://dev.twitter.com/ads/reference/post/accounts/account_id/tweet

Comment: @JoshD. I try to do what you said, but i can't found that link on the source page of a tweet. is it deprecated?

Comment: @French_FitGirl nope it's still there: https://i.imgur.com/sh8kYc2.png. Make sure you're using the dev tools view, so you get the complete source.

Comment: I've just tried doing this and I have the impression that twitter caught up to this because it doesn't seem to work anymore. In early 2019 it still worked, but now the tweet simply displays the copied URL (pic.twitter.com/whatever which points to the deleted tweet. :-( Is it everyone or just me?

Comment: I used this method also (instead I deleted the tweet with the image I needed and up to early this year it then showed the pic.twitter.com id). But it doesn’t work any longer. It seems that with the new API pic.twitter.com is deprecated.

Comment: March 2021: In order to get the "pic.twitter.com" link you need to click twitters "embed tweet" (3 dot menu) - this will give you an HTML snippet and inside there you will find the "pic.twitter.com" link.  You can also the "https://t.co/" link from the twitter page meta too!

Answer (score 3):

You have to use  twitter card:https://dev.twitter.com/cards/overview.
make sure you use the summary card and not the photo card which has deprecated.
here is how you do it:

```
       <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />      
       <meta name="twitter:site" content="@tapaway" />
       <meta name="twitter:title" content="bla bla" />
       <meta name="twitter:description" content="bla bla" />
       <meta name="twitter:image" content="http://www.tapawayapp.com/assets/images/share.png" />
       <meta name="twitter:url" content="https://tapaway.parseapp.com//share.html" />
```

> you can test yor cards here:https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator